# How does the great Shamanic lodge choose which causes and governments to support?

Tags: magic, warfare, politics, religion, organizations

The **Great Shamanic Lodge** is [the prevailing Order](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheOrder) in my world. The Lodge was was founded during the Divine war,and during that tumultuous time was far more militant and possessed a more grandiose name The Asura Host. The Host lead the fight to free the mortal race from the tyranny of [the Daeva](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WitchSpecies) and their supernal masters the Old Gods. The Shaman gained [the power](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PsychicPowers) to appose the Daeva by using their accumulated lore to divisive a way to entering into a precarious symbiosis with other worldly creatures.

After the war the Host demilitarized took and readopted their humble name of Shaman, swearing to devote their strength to helping the world and all its peoples. Do to their actions during the war The Great Shamanic Lodge has a near religious level of deference paid to it, and it is beholden to no government.

What I am wondering is how does the Lodge chose which causes its Shaman will lend their power to?

Comment: They sound like Jedi...

Comment: @XandarTheZenon that compression is going to be inevitable. But the Aes Sedai are much closer structurally to how I see the Lodge.

Comment: Tris this one is pretty clearly idea generation.

Comment: @James  Tris agrees with you.

Comment: @James No its about politics, the back story was for "flavor".   I have powerful (supposedly) neutral organization with a cause of"protecting and bettering" mankind.  I was wondering what causes would support it , into which situations would it intervene and what causes would it back.

Answer (score 3):

One issue of super national organizations is "*Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?*" (Who guards the guardians?). The problem in the setup is this is not just a super national organization like OCHA, but one with massive material and martial resources available.

Over the years, this will breed two responses. Various nations and groups will be appealing to the organization for assistance against whoever they perceive to be their enemies, and of course they will be using everything from persuasion, bribes and even threats of force to attempt to enlist the order to bring their resources to the issue.

The other response will be jealousy and resentment that the Order are not bound by the same rules as everyone else, and that they have real or imagined access to powers and resources beyond that available for ordinary mortals and kings.

In the real world, this might be close to the situation that developed as the *Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon* (Knights Templar) gained military and financial power over the course of two centuries. Eventually, they fell under the jealous gaze of King Philip the Fair, who managed to seize the members of the order and attempted to seize their wealth as well. (How the money escaped is not clear today, although one theory is the Knights operated a banking system similar in conception to today's and the "wealth" was in the form of accounts receivable and loans rather than the piles of gold coins King Phillip seems to have imagined).

Given the swirling currents that will surround the Order in your setup, I suggest that the most likely outcome after centuries of receiving requests, bribes and fighting attempts to seize their wealth and power, the Order will have become somewhat inward looking and to all intents and purposes have been corrupted. The Grand Master will certainly intervene on your side of the conflict, *if* you can come up with the proper price. What the proper price for an organization like that is up to you, of course.

The other outcome is their growing power and hubris will eventually call down the wrath of the gods, much like the Valar caused the downfall of Númenor (recounted in the Silmarillion ).

Comment: While I had imagined political complications for the Lodge, they were not the ones that you raised. Nations resenting the Lodge monopolizing psychic power/devices, Shaman and sometimes entire chapters going rogue, hostility towards the Adepts(what the Daeva became after the war) do to their history and the selling of their services to the highest bidder.

Answer (score 1):

You have portrayed your Lodge not only as the prevailing order, but as a house of peacekeepers whose purpose is in "helping the world and all its peoples". They also have free reign and hold no one sovereign to themselves. As to whether they are involved or passive with regards to external events you haven't made their nature apparent.

To truly "control" (bad word) everyone and keep the peace everywhere they would also have to be everywhere. They do not bow to the rules of these places and seem to have the power to enforce their will even with resistance, which could of course be avoided with diplomatic lubrication.

This can be resolved by having the equivalent of embassies in major locations for fast response time, a larger coverage and easier access to the state of affairs in many places. With this they should receive ample warning of impeding threat and could from these forward bases of operation dissuade or prevent altercations well in advance. By having an embassy everywhere they ensure a face of neutrality and can under this mask of neutrality target and deal with any single party which is a legitimate offender to "rules" without siding with that party's enemies.

Their paring with otherworldly beings also differentiates them from their charges and passively separates them in a way that gives them further "superiority" and claim to declare oneself such a powerful peacekeeping entity.

Should all these precautions fail and the hand is forced. The lodge would most likely seek a path that keeps closest to its ideals while still ensuring its survival. They have shown to be willing to take precarious, possibly risky decisions to achieve their ends. One would assume they could resort to drastic means.

As to which "side" in an option of two. Most likely the one where they survive, if survival is more important than risking becoming something one doesn't wish to be.

Comment: The Lodge in modern terms is a peacekeeping/humanitarian organization. Most of what they do entails civil works, healing the sick and helping to produce higher crop yields; they also attempt police psychics. The Lodges allegiance to no nation is a very political move. The Lodge doesn't want the shaman to become the next great psychic tyrants of the world,they didn't fight a centuries long war to free humanity  just to turn around and enslave it themselves. The Lodge also has some code of conduct meant to protect mere mortals from them.